# How can I access active directory to load email groups into an array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET How to get List of Groups in Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323536/asp-net-how-to-get-list-of-groups-in-active-directory)

I am creating a web form for position changes in my company and want to load email groups into an array to list in a listbox.  Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will give you all the mail enabled groups from AD. I don't have a Domain to test it on right now however. 
Of course you would have to add a reference to System.DirectoryServices

```
  string domainName = "yourDomain";
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=" + domainName + ",DC=com");
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        string query = "(&(&(& (mailnickname=*) (| (objectCategory=group) ))))";
        search.Filter = query;
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");

        SearchResultCollection mySearchResultColl = search.FindAll();

        List<string> groups = new List<string>();

        foreach (SearchResult sr in mySearchResultColl)
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
            groups.Add(de.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use directory services to query the store.  Make sure the account that executes the query has access writes to those items inside AD.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) for more information.