# System.DirectoryServices compilation problems

Tags: active-directory, compiler-errors, asp.net-3.5, directoryservices

I'm using the code here : [ASP.NET How to get List of Groups in Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323536/asp-net-how-to-get-list-of-groups-in-active-directory)

Specifically :

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

DirectoryEntry objADAM = default(DirectoryEntry); //compiler error!
```

**Problem: compiler says that it doesn't know what DirectoryEntry is.**

I tried to add it to my web.config:

```
      <assemblies>
          <!-- ... -->
          <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
      </assemblies>
```

But it didn't seem to help so I tried to add a reference:

[image]

[Someone suggested](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t59172-imports-system-directoryservices-cannot-be-found.html) setting `Copy Local = True` but that didn't help either.

I noticed that I don't see a reference for `System.DirectoryServices` - only `System.DirectoryServices.Accountmanagement`

[image]

Can anyone help me get this code to compile? I'm not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the .net 3.5 filter off in the Add Reference dialog, and then put a reference in your project to:

`System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`

You can take the filter off by changing you project setting : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Comment: I don't know how to remove .Net 3.5 filter from "Add Reference" dialog. However, I directly added the above said line in web.config and it worked alright. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `DirectoryEntry` from the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace - you need to add a reference to the `System.DirectoryServices` assembly - **NOT** the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` assembly!

[image]